# Git version number shows the file was newly added but it's actually changed some code

Tags: git

Have you encountered this problem before?

In my IDEA, the Git history shows the file was changed, some code was removed.

But if I copy the **vision number** to the commit message, it shows the file was **newly added.**

*Some details:*

In my IDEA, it shows that accountRoleLocalService has been deleted.

[image]

In the Git ID link, the class file seems new added.

https://github.com/JanisZhang/liferay-portal/commit/792b40a3dfbbd6a89347f38e724fccbdb863f984

Anyone can give me a hand?

Comment: After I click resume git log Indexing it seems consistent with the gitk history. 

but it's weird the commit message says Delete xxxxx but actually added a file...

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a refactoring, where a file:

- has been renamed
- has been edited to delete portion of the code

Said deleted portion has been reported to a new separated file.

Sometimes Git reports a [rename as a deletion + creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60185970/6309) (also [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60231214/6309)).